# Spring Boot wants @Component class to be a @Bean in @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, components, javabeans

When I am testing my `@Component` class, Spring boot tells me that this class should be declared as `@Bean` in `@Configuration` class:

```
Field c in org.accountingSpringBoot.AccountingSpringBootApplication required a bean of type 'org.util.Cryptography' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.util.Cryptography' in your configuration.
```

Code:

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccountingSpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;
    @Autowired
    Cryptography c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(AccountingSpringBootApplication.class);
    builder.headless(false);

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = builder.run(args);
    // SpringApplication.run(AccountingSpringBootApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(c.decrypt(c.encrypt("password")));
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = "singleton")
    public SessionHandler sessionHandler() {
    return new SessionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = "singleton")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    try {
        sessionFactory = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecretKey secretKey() {
    String secretKey = env.getProperty("crypto.secretkey");
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKey);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length,
        env.getProperty("crypto.algorithm"));
    return originalKey;
    }
}
```

`@Component` class:

```
@Component
public class Cryptography {
    @Autowired
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    private Cipher cipher; // = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    public Cryptography() {
    try {
        System.out.println("hhhhh");
        this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {
    byte[] plainTextByte = plainText.getBytes();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    String encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(encryptedByte);
    return encryptedText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception {
    Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    byte[] encryptedTextByte = decoder.decode(encryptedText);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
    String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
    return decryptedText;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see your tests, but do you have `@SpringBootTest` in your tests ? That way you will be able to use the `SpringBootContextLoader` that will create your beans.

Comment: @GabLeg  by testing i meant invoking `decrypt()` & `encrypt()` in `run(String... args)`

Comment: Ohhh I see, my bad! Just to make sure, is your package name `org.util` ? If not, you are probably using an external library that is `org.util.Cryptography`. Make sure to import your `Cryptography` class.

Comment: Yes, my package name is `org.util` - this class is implemented by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show package declarations in your code, but the error shows that `AccountingSpringBootApplication` is in package `org.accountingSpringBoot`, and that `Cryptography` is in package `org.util`.

The `@SpringBootApplication` enables component scanning of the package and sub-packages of the class carrying the annotation, i.e. of package `org.accountingSpringBoot`.

Since `Cryptography` is in package `org.util`, it is not scanned, so the `@Component` is not seen by the Spring container.

You can:

- Move `Cryptography` to a sub-package of `org.accountingSpringBoot`, e.g. `org.accountingSpringBoot.util`
- Move `AccountingSpringBootApplication` to package `org` *(not recommended)*
- Explicitly specify which packages to scan:

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"org.accountingSpringBoot", "org.util"})
  ```
- Re-arrange your package structure.
  **I recommend this**, since you current packages are too generic, e.g.:

  ```
  org.janlan.accounting.AccountingApplication
  org.janlan.accounting.util.Cryptography
  ```

  Where `janlan` could be your company name, or your name, or something like that.

You should read the documentation about the recommended package structure of a Spring Boot application: [Locating the Main Application Class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using default app layout, and so your `org.util.Cryptography` class is not discovered.

There are a few possible solutions

- use `@ComponentScan`
- use default package layout. Check [Locating the Main Application Class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class)
- Remove the @Component from Cryptography class (it is not discovered anyway). Declare a method annotated with @Bean in one of your configuration classes that returns an instance of Cryptography. (Your configuration class uses this approach with a few beans)